# IIF and Date logic and format for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have the following code

```
=IIF(Month(Fields!effectivedate.Value) <> Month(Now()), Now(), Fields!effectdate.Value)
```

In this code I check to see if `Fields!effectivedate.Value` is the current month.

- If it is the current month then it displays `Fields!effectivedate.Value`.
- If it is not the current month then it displays the current date.

In addition to doing this check I would like to check for another value,   `fields!Freeze.Value`

Here is how it would look in VB.NET code

```
If fields!Freeze.Value = true
     Fields!effectdate.Value
else
     IIF(Month(Fields!effectivedate.Value) <> Month(Now()), Now(), Fields!effectdate.Value)
end if
```

How would I write this in SSRS code?

Please ask for further clarification if i have failed to explain something properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest the IIfs:

```
=IIf(Fields!Freeze.Value, Fields!effectdate.Value, IIF(Month(Fields!effectivedate.Value) <> Month(Now()), Now(), Fields!effectdate.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a nested `IIf` function as started by @lc. however you need to be more clear what you want to check for in the `Freeze` field.

For example you can check for blanks using the `IsNothing()` function, or if its a booleon you **may** need to see if `Fields!Freeze.Value = 1`.